# Split function with multiple delimiters such as ( and ,

Tags: python, regex

Anyone help me with multiple delimiters for split function?
For instance, given a string `"#1(X,Y)"`, I want to use delimiters such as `(, ',', )` to get a set like `('#1', 'X', 'Y')`

I have tried `re.split(' \\( | , | \\) ', '#1(X,Y)')` but get
`['#1', 'X, Y', '']`

Comment: You could replace using `.replace()` and do so for each delimiter and replace with a coma or sth, then You can just split by coma

Comment: If you want to split by `(` and `,` and `)`, then that sounds like you an expression like `'[(),]'`. I don't know what that expression in your question is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't do what you say it does.

```py
>>> s = "#1(X,Y)" 
>>> import re
>>> re.split(' \\( | , | \\) ', s)
['#1(X,Y)']
```

Your string doesn't contain any of those expressions; you probably mean

```py
>>> re.split('\\(|,|\\)', s)
['#1', 'X', 'Y', '']
```

which can be refactored to something like

```py
>>> re.split(r'\s*[(,)]\s*', s)
['#1', 'X', 'Y', '']
```

to use a simpler and more elegant and idiomatic regex, and also allow for optional whitespace around the delimiters.

There is no sane way really to prevent Python from finding an empty string before or after a delimiter which is adjacent to beginning or end of string; probably just filter out empty strings from the beginning and end, or preprocess the string to remove delimiter characters from the beginning and the end before the regex match.

Comment: However, your input string looks vaguely like you are actually trying to parse expressions, which should probably use a parser instead. Regex will fail if you need to handle e.g. nested parentheses.